discord.py - Voice Client not playing source
I was recently creating a Discord Bot and wanted to create a /effect boom command. After running the command, the client joins the channel and should play the specified source in the code.
I don't know why, but it connects and doesn't play anything. Here's the output:
[2024-07-11 14:27:51] [INFO ] discord.voice_client: Connecting to voice... [2024-07-11 14:27:51] [INFO ] discord.voice_client: Starting voice handshake... (connection attempt 1)
Here's the code: (I used from discord import *)
`
class Effect(app_commands.Group):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(
        name="effect",
        description="Creates chaos in your VC"
    )

@self.command(name="boom", description="Plays a boom sound in your voice channel")
@app_commands.guild_only()
async def effect_boom(inc: Interaction):
    if not inc.guild:
        await inc.response.send_message(
            embed=Embed(
                description="You must be in a guild to perform this command! <a:amongus:1255247106252214276>",
                color=0xFCFCED
            ),
            ephemeral=True
        )
        return
    if not inc.user.voice:
        await inc.response.send_message(
            embed=Embed(
                description="You must be in a voice channel to perform this command! <a:amongus:1255247106252214276>",
                color=0xFCFCED
            ),
            ephemeral=True
        )
        return
    if inc.guild.me.voice:
        await inc.response.send_message(
            embed=Embed(
                description="I'm currently in a voice channel, you're in queue...",
                color=0xFCFCED
            ),
            ephemeral=True
        )
        while inc.guild.me.voice:
            ...
        source = PCMVolumeTransformer(FFmpegPCMAudio("bobo/audio/boom.mp3"))
        await voice_client.VoiceClient(inc.client, inc.user.voice.channel).connect(reconnect=False, timeout=None, self_deaf=True)
        await voice_client.VoiceClient(inc.client, inc.user.voice.channel).play(source, after=(await voice_client.VoiceClient(inc.client, inc.user.voice.channel).disconnect(force=True)))
        await inc.edit_original_response(
            embed=Embed(
                description="The boom effect has been played!",
                color=0xFCFCED
            )
        )
        return
    while inc.guild.me.voice:
        ...
    source = PCMVolumeTransformer(FFmpegPCMAudio("bobo/audio/boom.mp3"))
    await voice_client.VoiceClient(inc.client, inc.user.voice.channel).connect(reconnect=False, timeout=None, self_deaf=True)
    await voice_client.VoiceClient(inc.client, inc.user.voice.channel).play(source, after=(await voice_client.VoiceClient(inc.client, inc.user.voice.channel).disconnect(force=True)))
    await inc.response.send_message(
        embed=Embed(
            description="The boom effect has been played!",
            color=0xFCFCED
        )
    )

`
Any kind of help appreciated!

You should try doing this to play an audio source in a VoiceChannel:
voiceChannelConnect = await voiceChannel.connect()
audioSource = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:\\Path\\To\\ffmpeg.exe", source="sound.mp3")        
voiceChannelConnect.play(audioSource)


It works, thanks a lot!

Happy to help, would you mind marking my answer as solved? It would help both you and me out alot! Thanks in advance!
